# Apache ODE and JAX-WS 2.0

Tags: jax-ws, apache-ode

I am trying Apache ODE for evaluation.
It seems Apache ODE runs on AXIS2 for webservices.

Has anybody tried to configure Apache ODE with JAX-WS 2.0 instead of AXIS 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should look for another products derived from apache ode because Ode 1.3.5 runs with axis2 web services implementation. For this last version, ode cannot offer another web service implementation alternative and maybe this won't change in a nearest future because this version has not evolved since 2011.

Other options are:

- switchyard (at jboss) [some riftsaw project migrations]. very
  promissing
- wso2-bps
- intalio
- bpel-g (at google code)

Answer (score 3):

Please have a look at JBoss Riftsaw. It is based on Apache ODE and adds a JBoss WS integration layer, which is AFAIK JAX-WS compatible.